# Django , Changing color of Boolean widget in list display

Tags: django-admin, django-models, django-widget

I have a Django Boolean Field which is shown with pretty 'on' 'off' buttons in the list display (green and red). Is it possible to have a third state like yellow or blue, indicating state is unknown.

PS : I have read about NullBooleanField, but that doesn't change my widget.
All I need is, Django to display a third color based on a third value for my boolean field.

Comment: I would very much like to upvote this question, but it is against my policy to upvote questions that have not accepted a working answer.

Answer (score 3):

The rules for this are [buried pretty deep in the Django admin app](https://github.com/django/django/blob/511a53b3142551a1bc3093ed1b6655f57634f510/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py#L175).

```
def _boolean_icon(field_val):
    icon_url = static('admin/img/icon-%s.gif' %
                      {True: 'yes', False: 'no', None: 'unknown'}[field_val])
    return format_html('<img src="{}" alt="{}" />', icon_url, field_val)
```

This is then [called in `admin/utils.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2be621e44c1b5b68c895383f3e20b1f17ddb447a/django/contrib/admin/utils.py#L371), so changing it to support multiple values may be tricky.

Fortunately, it does handle the `NullBooleanField` and there is an image for "unknown values" shown below:

> [image: icon-unknown.gif] `icon-unknown.gif`
>
> [image: icon-yes.gif] `icon-yes.gif`
>
> [image: icon-no.gif] `icon-no.gif`

Comment: Thanks, but how do you use the NullBooleanField to make it display. I used it in ModelForms to declare my Boolean variable as NullBooleanField. But it doesn't display the third image.

Comment: [UPDATE] - got it working after altering the field to NullBooleanSelect. Gave the value as None when required and got the third image working